# SOAP - Nonce key generation

Tags: objective-c, swift, soap-client, nonce

I stuck with a SOAP service security. In testing with SoapUI, I find a generated Nonce key.
How to generate Nonce key? I have username, password (type: password text), timestamp which Nonce key seems to be it generated from them.

Thanks for advance!

Comment: Did you click the check box for Preferences -> HTTP Settings -> Authentication Premptively and make sure the credentials are provided in Webservice request properties. By the way, you do not have to manually add them in the each request, instead just have empty Header tag in the request, soapui will automatically add those details.

Comment: That for SoapUI, I need programmatically generation.

Comment: Temporary I'm using base64(openUUID) and it works.

Comment: Well, it was not metioned as you wanted in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using base64(openUUID) and it works.